# Avoid Sign in prompt from IIS Server for windows authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, iis-10

I have a web application which will be hosted in intranet IIS server. The requirement is that the Login endpoint should perform LDAPS authentication. In local dev environment everything went well. But when this is placed in real-time IIS server or in my local IIS Server , it is prompting for a sign in as shown in this image:

[image: sign_in_prompt_error]

I don't want this to happen. I will allow requests from any windows user and my Authentication endpoint will take care of handling.

Where should I make changes? Is it in my .NET6 web api code or do the IIS Server settings need to be changed?

Steps I performed in IIS:

1. I launched my local IIS server in Admin mode.
2. In my site, I click on "Anuthentication" => Anonymous Authentication = disabled => Windows Authentication = Enabled;
3. I tried check/uncheck on Extended protection and Enable-Kernel Mode.

Nothing helped here. The sign in prompt still exists.

I found a solution on the internet saying, Go to Control Panel => Internet Options => Internet => Authentication Logon => select Anuthenticate logon with current user and password, but this also did not work for me.

my .net6 program.cs code to handle CORS and Windows authentication is:

```
//c# .net6 code
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var corsOrigins = builder.Configuration["Cors:origins"].Split(",");//Taking origins from config. file
var corsMethods = builder.Configuration["Cors:methods"].Split(",");
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins(corsOrigins)
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .WithMethods(corsMethods)
               .AllowCredentials();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

Changes I made in IIS are also shown in this image:

[image: iis_settings].

Also, I don't have any roles/groups in IIS.

Finally, I don't want to get this automatic sign in event triggered on my API endpoints. The actual authentication logic to handle is already taken care by an Authentication endpoint by recognizing the windows identity of the user and performing LDAPS.

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Like the answers below pointed out, you must understand clearly what is Windows authentication, before moving on. In short, the prompt indicates the browser does not work very well with IIS/Windows authentication, which requires extra configuration and different browsers use different settings. You can find tons of discussions in the past decades on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

> Steps I performed in IIS:
>
> --Firstly, I launched my local IIS server in Admin mode.
>
> 1. In my site, I click on "Anuthentication" => Anonymous Authentication = disabled => Windows Authentication = Enabled;

The thing to understand here is Windows Authentication is **not** LDAPS authentication. If you really want to do LDAPS, you need to allow **Forms Authentication**. This is what will let you build your own login page with a *Form* allowing the user to login. You then must also grant Anonymous access to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

When windows authentication is enabled in IIS, a login window prompted appears, which is expected behavior, not an error.

I agree with [Joel Coehoorn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn) answer, below tricky way can help you implement this feature.

If you still want to use windows authentication, but don't want the prompt windows. You can enable the `Anonymous Authentication`, and disable the `Windows Authentication`.

Then you can [refer my sample code here to implement this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77791032/7687666).

**Here is the test result**

[image]

Comment: "which is expected behavior" is not 100% true. Proper browser configuration can suppress the prompt.

Comment: Hi @LexLi I mean there is no additional configuration, which is the expected behavior.

Comment: Hi @JasonPan, your suggestion helped me a lot. Now I am able to identify the windows identity from anonymous authentication. My frontend is Angular and I used withCredentials: true in the GET request. Things are working fine in development. But when I place this in IIS, and only enabled Anonymous Authentication on both frontend and backend sites. But the identity is not being recognised in login endpoint. Is there something to configure in IIS?

Comment: @KarumanchiSrikanth identity ? Does your project integrate other authentication methods?

Comment: @JasonPan After login, further authentication is verified by cookie set in the response of the login endpoint

Comment: Hello @KarumanchiSrikanth Try to comment this line `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();`.

Comment: @KarumanchiSrikanth And I am also interest in this issue, do you mind create a brand new sample project, I would like to check the further authentication. And please hide sensitive information to keep your data safely.